# Print GPU usage in conky

Tags: shell, conky

I cannot print my GPU usage I have the following regexp:

```
${execgraph 16,235 $(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv -l 5 | sed -n '2p' | grep -Po "\\d+")}
```

Which prints the wanted value but for some reason the graph won´t render.

What am I missing?

[image: conky]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conky includes an `nvidiagraph` argument that seems directed to what you're trying to do. See `man conky` for details. Unfortunately, I'm unable to test it, as I have an AMD GPU.

Comment: ${voffset 5}${alignc}${color6}${nvidiagraph temp  15,235 -l}${font}${color}

Did the trick. But i could not find it on the official docs it was somehow hidden in the code

Comment: Glad you got it working. If by the "official docs" you mean the wiki in the conky GitHub repository, you're right, it does seem that it's not listed there. However, it was added to the files in the repository used to generate the conky man page back in [a commit from Jun 2016](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/commit/3753e2a95bfc8798afb8e845112f52f2891372df#diff-139d544b821b13ebea14f1b0fe18577222e415c2966e3a3511c4196055232202).